# Priority error while using variable

Tags: python

```
print "Password?"

main = 1.0
tries = 1
Pass = raw_input()
if Pass == "hi": print "Granted access."
elif Pass == "swag": print "really?"
else:
        print "Wrong, try again."
        print "Wrong", tries, "try."
        tries = tries + 1

print "Password?"
Pass = raw_input()
if Pass == "hi": print "Granted access."
else:
        print "Wrong,", tries, """tries.
try again?""" #test # line 18
        tries = tries + 1
answer = raw_input()
if answer == "Yes": print "Password?"
 Pass = raw_input() # line 22
 if Pass == "hi": print "WOW SUCH PASS"
        else:
                print "Wrong,", tries, "tries...aborting"      
tries = tries + 1
else: # line 27
        print "Okay."
```

Check this code.

I'm trying on line 18 ask if the user want to try answering password again.
And if it's yes, ask for password and check to my "Pass".
If the user does not want to answer the password, he should be redirected to code line 27.

But already on line 22 there's something wrong.

I've tried several ways to format this code and I'm pretty new. Someone wanna help out on this one?

Edit: Sorry for the misleading Title, was very unsure of how to put this.

Comment: What is the error message given by the Python interpreter?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The problems are because you have incorrect and inconsistent whitespace/indentation

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your indenting correct. Lines 21 and 22 seem odd, as well as the hanging `else` on 24. You may want to avoid the inline `if cond: pass` construct for a time, until you get the hang of Python's indenting.

I may or may not have grouped your blocks correctly, but here how your code should *look*:

```
if answer == "Yes":
    print "Password?"
    Pass = raw_input()
    if Pass == "hi":
        print "WOW SUCH PASS"
    else:
        print "Wrong,", tries, "tries...aborting"      
    tries = tries + 1
else:
    print "Okay."
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanded from comment: python requires you to properly indent your code. 4 spaces for each block. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for the list of requirements.

```
print "Password?"                                                                                                                                                                                            

main = 1.0 
tries = 1 
Pass = raw_input()
if Pass == "hi":
    print "Granted access."
elif Pass == "swag":
    print "really?"
else:
    print "Wrong, try again."
    print "Wrong", tries, "try."
    tries = tries + 1 

print "Password?"
Pass = raw_input()
if Pass == "hi":
    print "Granted access."
else:
    print "Wrong,", tries, """tries.
try again?"""  # test # line 18
    tries = tries + 1 
answer = raw_input()
if answer == "Yes":
    print "Password?"
    Pass = raw_input()  # line 22
    if Pass == "hi":
        print "WOW SUCH PASS"
    else:
        print "Wrong,", tries, "tries...aborting"
        tries = tries + 1 
else:  # line 27
    print "Okay."
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a correctly indented version of your code. It's correct in terms of syntax but maybe not in terms of behaviour - that is for you to investigate. You should read the introductory Python tutorial and http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ as suggested in the comments.

```
print "Password?"

main = 1.0
tries = 1
Pass = raw_input()

if Pass == "hi":
    print "Granted access."
elif Pass == "swag":
    print "really?"
else:
    print "Wrong, try again."
    print "Wrong", tries, "try."
    tries = tries + 1

print "Password?"
Pass = raw_input()

if Pass == "hi":
    print "Granted access."
else:
    print "Wrong,", tries, "tries.try again?"
    tries = tries + 1

answer = raw_input()
if answer == "Yes":
    print "Password?"
    Pass = raw_input()

    if Pass == "hi":
        print "WOW SUCH PASS"
    else:
        print "Wrong,", tries, "tries...aborting"      
        tries = tries + 1
else:
        print "Okay."
```

Answer (score 0):

Liberally rewritten:

```
users = {
    'hi': 'hi',
    'swag': None,
    'nsa': 'hail_the_fatherland'
}

def validate_user():
    for tries in range(3):
        user = raw_input('User: ')
        pwd  = raw_input('Password: ')
        if user in users and users[user] == pwd:
            print('Access Granted')
            return True
    print('Go away, you l33t h4ck3r')
    return False

def main():
    if validate_user():
        print('Direct me, master!')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```